# C# launching command line with escape characters

Tags: c#, string, command-line, escaping

Here is the string in C# as the cmd.exe argument:

```
 fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"\"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" \"{2}\"\"", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir);
```

where `_fijiExeFile`, `_ijmFile` and `_inputDir` are built in from UI.

The third parameter, however, is observed to be

```
C:\Users\my.Unit\Favorites\Downloads\fiji.app (1)\Untitled001"\
```

when it gets passed to the ImageJ macro script, whereas it should be

```
 C:\Users\my.Unit\Favorites\Downloads\fiji.app (1)\Untitled001\
```

I am wondering is there anyway to get rid of the `"` at the end of `C:\Users\my.Unit\Favorites\Downloads\fiji.app (1)\Untitled001"\`, before the `\` ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Someone told me to remove the last \" and that works. I am wondering if you can post your answer here and explain a little why this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is the escape character for a string, so this string: `"\""` will display as `"`.

The third parameter in your format is `\"{2}\"\"` which will be displayed as `"<value of _inputDir>""`.

Notice that extra `"` there? that's what you need to remove by changing the format to `\"{2}\"`:

```
fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"\"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir);
```

Comment: I thought the last \" was paired with the \" at the beginning right after the /C to handle the escape characters? Basically what I had was \"myWholeCommandLine\"

Comment: I don't know which escape characters you are referring to, but quotes ("") are usually used in command prompts to allow for spaces between them, for example if your file is saved under Program Files. However all your inputs are already surrounded by quotes, I don't think another pair is needed.

Comment: In the end you need to try it out and see.