# launching command line handling escape characters

Tags: c#, string, command-line, escaping

I have command line argument (launched in C#):

```
 fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"\"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" \"{2}\" {3} \"{4}\" {5} {6}", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir, redirStr, _logFile, headlessOption, resStr);
```

where string is built in strings, and the only problem is from the third and forth strings: `_inputDir`, `redirStr`. They are actually

```
_inputDir = "D:\\fiji\\blobimg\\";
redirStr = ">";
_logFile = "D:\\fiji\\blobimg\\log.txt";
```

If the command argument is like above, then the actual _inputDir received by the script, which is launched by this command line, will be

```
D:\fiji\blobimg"
```

but if I change the argument to

```
 fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"\"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" \"{2} {3} \"{4}\" {5} {6}", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir, redirStr, _logFile, headlessOption, resStr);
```

the actual string received will be (**problem here is the third string interferes with the forth string, which it should not**)

```
D:\fiji\blobimg\ > D:\fiji\blobimg\Output\log.txt
```

I really want to have, neither without the `"`, nor messed up with the string following.

```
D:\fiji\blobimg\
```

so how should I change the argument of the command line to make it work?

**EDIT:** Hope this is useful info

`fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"{0}\"", _fijiExeFile);`

will run,

but

`fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" \"{2}\", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir);`

will **not** run. I have no idea why. Very strange. I think I follow all the rules, but it did not work.

Comment: I have read your question couple of times and didn't get your problem. what is wrong when you remove \"?

Comment: @Vitaliy if I remove \", then the {3} will be automatically combined with {2}. {2} should just be D:\fiji\blobimg\, but if I only use \"{2}, then it becomes D:\fiji\blob\ > D:\fiji\blob\Output\log.txt, which is {2}+{3}. Let me know if it is not clear still.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588702/c-sharp-launching-command-line-with-escape-characters

Comment: Difference is that when {2} string at the end, the solution in the old threads worked. However, it it is in the middle, it will interfere with the string following it. So it is similar, but a new questions.

Comment: I really hope someone can help, I tried different combinations, and following exactly many sources suggested about escape sequences, but it just did not work. Should it be this hard?

Comment: It's difficult to tell, because you don't give nearly enough information for anybody to help you, but why do you have two `\"` at the very beginning of your string? Try replacing this part `"/C \"\"{0}\"` with `"/C \"{0}\"`

Comment: What else you need if you don't think the information is not enough?

Comment: @NickXTsui: How about actual code? With actual values for all the parameters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your problem is an extra `\"` right before your first place holder.

Try:

```
var fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" \"{2}\" {3} \"{4}\" {5} {6}", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir, redirStr, _logFile, headlessOption, resStr);
```

Looking at [this fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/hLzfpr) the logged text looks about right to me for a command line.

```
/C "foo" -macro "bar" "D:\fiji\blobimg\" > "D:\fiji\blobimg\log.txt" headless resStr
```

Comment: This is exactly how I tried first time, but the problem is that, the foo.exe is not going to launch, which I cannot explain.

Comment: fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"{0}\"", _fijiExeFile); will run, but fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" \"{2}\", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir); will not run. I have no idea why. Very strange.

Comment: @NickXTsui: Then you have a different problem. But if I'm going to get down voted for trying to help then I won't bother with it anymore.

Comment: I did not vote it down. On the other hand, I will accept your answer, because the this fiddle tool helped.

Comment: It was with the fiddle tool that helped me to see that was actually the _inputDir that has an extra \\ at the end, which caused the problem.